# Grails documentation on RestfulController: nested resources query contains id == id

Tags: grails, groovy

I'm working on a Grails RestfulController and bumped into this strange query within the documentation, section 9.1.5.1 (https://grails.github.io/grails-doc/latest/guide/single.html#extendingRestfulController), having id == id:

```
@Override
protected Book queryForResource(Serializable id) {
    Book.where {
        id == id && author.id = params.authorId
    }.find()
}
```

Initially thought it was a problem in the doco, but actually wrote the code and it indeed only works with the id == id. Codenarc also detects the strange comparison and the generated Hibernate query has it as expected.
Could anyone help me understand it? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 id   ==  id  
|___|    |___|
  |        |
  |        |
  |      id value passed as method parameter
  |
id property from domain class
```

The left hand side of an expression in `where` query or `DetachedCriteria` is always a reference of a property from the domain class.

Similar to :

```
select a from Author as a where a.id = :id
```

where `:id` will be the passed in parameter to the query